# Filter Drupal 7 View by Menu Depth

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I need to create a list of nodes(with links) that shows nodes of a couple specific content type, but also filters out nodes that are more than 1 level of menu depth lower than a specific node.

I've tried creating a menu block, but I see no options to filter by content type.
I've tried creating a view, but I see no options to filter by menu depth.

Anyone know the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to filter by menu depth? Are these categories or something? If so, you should probably be using taxonomy which would make the view you are after very simple to create.

Comment: @2pha I have 3 content types involved in this structure. Imagine A(1), B(3), and C(20). B and C both fall under A. In some cases, C is a child of B. When a C is a child of a B, I don't want it to appear in the collection of nodes that appears on A. Thus, menu depth. 

I also want it to be automated as much as possible, and I understand Taxonomy requires an extra step when the node is created.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "extra step". The fact that C is a child of A, but can also be a child of B seems to complicate things as far as taxonomy is concerned. 
Maybe you can try the menu node api module:https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_node and the menu node views module: https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_node_views

Answer (score 0):

Follow up: I just ended up using Taxonomy and setting a default node that it refers to. Not my ideal solution, but it gets the job done.